# Unit Testing for Web API, GET same ID

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, asp.net-web-api2

I'm at a lost for how to write a unit test for my web api GET by id method.

Here is what I have:

```
public void GetProduct_ShouldReturnSameID()
{
    var context = new TestModelContext();
    context.Products.Add(GetDemoProduct());

    var controller = new ProductsController(context);
    var result = controller.GetProduct(3) as OkNegotiatedContentResult<Product>;

    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    Assert.AreEqual(3, result.Content.Id);
}
```

And my controller method I'm trying to test

```
public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(int id)
{
    var product = (from t in db.Products.Include(t => t.Reviews)
                          .Where(t => t.Id == id)
                          select t);

    if (product == null || product.Count() == 0)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(product);
}
```

My test works find with my other controllers, but just not this one. I was wondering what is wrong with this? My test fails with an

> "Expected: not null But was: null"

```
public class TestModelContext : IModelContext {
    public TestModelContext() {
        this.Products = new TestProductDbSet();
    }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public int SaveChanges() {
        return 0;
    }
    public void MarkAsModified(Product item) { }

    public void Dispose() { }
}

public class TestProductDbSet : TestDbSet<Product> {
    public override Product Find(params object[] keyValues) {
        return this.SingleOrDefault(product => product.Id == (int)keyValues.Single());
    }
}

public class TestDbSet<T> : DbSet<T>, IQueryable, IEnumerable<T>
        where T : class
{
    ObservableCollection<T> _data;
    IQueryable _query;

    public TestDbSet()
    {
        _data = new ObservableCollection<T>();
        _query = _data.AsQueryable();
    }

    // ...

    public override T Create()
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    }

    public override TDerivedEntity Create<TDerivedEntity>()
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance<TDerivedEntity>();
    }

    public override ObservableCollection<T> Local
    {
        get { return new ObservableCollection<T>(_data); }
    }

    Type IQueryable.ElementType
    {
        get { return _query.ElementType; }
    }

    System.Linq.Expressions.Expression IQueryable.Expression
    {
        get { return _query.Expression; }
    }

    IQueryProvider IQueryable.Provider
    {
        get { return _query.Provider; }
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _data.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _data.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

GetDemoProduct:

```
Product GetDemoProduct()
{
    return new Product() { Id = 3, Name = "Name", Reviews = null };
}
```

Comment: Does your `TestModelContext` have an actual connection to a database or is it an in-memory context. I'm guessing that the `Include` in your linq query may causing the `product` variable to `null`

Comment: Updated with my `TestModelContext`

Comment: ok while this does show some more information we'll also need to see `TestProductDbSet` as that is what the query would be executing against

Comment: Added `TestProductDbSet` , I'm not really sure what the problem is though, unless it's actually part of the TestDbSet which is my base class for my test data?

Comment: Yeah we seem to be going down a rabbit hole here. how do you implement that base class for your test data. The long and short of it is that the query being executed for the dbset probably does not knwo how to handle the include which results in null as the include is linq to sql specific witch would be different for linq to entities. try trouble shooting it by excluding the include and see if it returns data

Comment: I've tried excluded only the include and it was still null, but when I got rid of the whole linq expression, it was fine.Updated with my base class

Comment: and now finally need `GetDemoProduct` in order to create [mcve] to try and recreate your issue.

Comment: Added GetDemoProduct, Am I missing something in my base test class to handle linq expressions?

Comment: I'll check and let you know

Comment: Check updated answer. turn out it had nothing to do with the include after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the sample code there is no code path that would result in the method under test returning `null`.

It's either going to return a `NotFoundResult` or a `OkNegotiatedContentResult<Product>`

Given that it is possible for the method under test to return a `NotFoundResult` , if the `if (product == null || product.Count() == 0)` condition is met and the method does indeed return not found result, then the following in your test

```
...as OkNegotiatedContentResult<Product>;
```

trying to cast `NotFoundResult` as `OkNegotiatedContentResult<Product>` will cause the result to be `null`.

You should recheck your setup/configuration of your `TestModelContext` as your linq call is causing the `product` variable to be `null` which in turn causes the `NotFoundResult` to be returned.

**UPDATE:**

Ok was able to start testing it based on your updated details and found an issue i should have noticed earlier.

First I was getting an error when added fake Product to list and had to update the TestDbSet base class to include added entities. I'll assume it was omitted in the sample code.

```
public override T Add(T entity) {
    _data.Add(entity);
    return entity;
}
```

next in the method under test, given the name the method and the expectation in the test, it should be returning a single Product. You were returning the query which would also result in null when you did the cast in the test.

```
public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(int id) {
    var product = (from t in db.Products.Include(t => t.Reviews)
                          .Where(t => t.Id == id)
                   select t);

    if (product == null || product.Count() == 0) {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(product.First());
}
```

When the above two changes were made, the test passed as expected.

Comment: You, my friend, are a lifesaver. Been ripping hairs off my head for a few days because of this. :)

Comment: Apologies for not seeing it sooner in the code. Was only when I was able to run the example that I caught it. I was too focused on the null conditions and didn't realize you were returning the query

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the controller is returning a `null` as the result.  Most likely the Products table and/or the Reviews table does not include a value of 3 that you are passing in as the parameter to your web method.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I suspect. Your `GetDemoProduct()` method which returns the product you are adding does not have `Reviews`. Hence, your query:

```
var product = (from t in db.Products.Include(t => t.Reviews)
                      .Where(t => t.Id == id)
                      select t);
```

did not return any records. Just a thought. If you can show us your `GetDemoProduct()` then we can tell.